# Three pictures vertical aligned. How to make it right

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

When working with many pictures I always have problem with alignment. For now, my problem is illustrated in the following picture.

[image]

As one can see, the first image is nor aligned with the others two. I tried several tricks, but they did not work. So, I'm all ears. The code that generates the image is:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
              xmin=0,xmax=6,
              ymin=-2,ymax=6,
              width=7.5cm, height=5.5cm,
              grid,% <-- changed
              grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=white},
              clip mode=individual,
              xtick=\empty,
              ytick=\empty,
              legend style={at={(1.25,0.98)},anchor=north east},
              %hide axis,
              %hide y axis,
             ]
\addplot[only marks,
          mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},
          mark size=2pt, 
          color=black,
          %opacity=0.8,
          fill opacity = 0.2,
         ]
         table [x={x}, y={y}, col sep=comma] {csv/more/cloudall_5.csv};

\addplot[only marks,
          mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},
          mark size=2pt, 
          color=blue,
          %opacity=0.8,
          fill opacity = 0.2,
         ]
         table [x={x}, y={y}, col sep=comma] {csv/more/cloud_5.csv};

\addplot[color=red,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.5mm,
         ]
         {
          0.0421120183297*x +1.07550170479
         };

\addplot[color=red,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.5mm,
         ]
         {
          0.201422124812*x -1.65615183388
         };

\addplot[color=blue,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.5mm,
         ]
         {
          0.0605449027383*x -0.0877091819259
         };

\addplot[dashed,
          color=black,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.25mm,
         ]
         {
          0.121010298828*x -0.277350636346
         };
%\legend{ ,$RANSAC$,$MQ$,$ME$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
              xmin=0,xmax=6,
              ymin=-2,ymax=6,
              width=7.5cm, height=5.5cm,
              grid,% <-- changed
              grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=white},
              clip mode=individual,
              xtick=\empty,
              ytick=\empty,
              legend style={at={(1.25,0.98)},anchor=north east},
              %hide axis,
              %hide y axis,
             ]
\addplot[only marks,
          mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},
          mark size=2pt, 
          color=black,
          %opacity=0.8,
          fill opacity = 0.2,
         ]
         table [x={x}, y={y}, col sep=comma] {csv/more/cloudall_15.csv};

\addplot[only marks,
          mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},
          mark size=2pt, 
          color=blue,
          %opacity=0.8,
          fill opacity = 0.2,
         ]
         table [x={x}, y={y}, col sep=comma] {csv/more/cloud_15.csv};

\addplot[color=red,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.5mm,
         ]
         {
          -0.464299252633*x +2.83110734717
         };

\addplot[color=red,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.5mm,
         ]
         {
          0.335246577615*x -1.37932758104
         };

\addplot[color=blue,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.5mm,
         ]
         {
          -0.0631252062184*x +0.642992901914
         };

\addplot[dashed,
          color=black,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.25mm,
         ]
         {
          -0.0556622617388*x +0.679211007364
         };
%\legend{ ,$RANSAC$,$MQ$,$ME$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
              xmin=0,xmax=6,
              ymin=-2,ymax=6,
              width=7.5cm, height=5.5cm,
              grid,% <-- changed
              grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=white},
              clip mode=individual,
              xtick=\empty,
              ytick=\empty,
              legend style={at={(1.25,0.98)},anchor=north east},
              %hide axis,
              %hide y axis,
             ]
\addplot[only marks,
          mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},
          mark size=2pt, 
          color=black,
          %opacity=0.8,
          fill opacity = 0.2,
         ]
         table [x={x}, y={y}, col sep=comma] {csv/more/cloudall_20.csv};

\addplot[only marks,
          mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},
          mark size=2pt, 
          color=blue,
          %opacity=0.8,
          fill opacity = 0.2,
         ]
         table [x={x}, y={y}, col sep=comma] {csv/more/cloud_20.csv};

\addplot[color=red,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.5mm,
         ]
         {
          -0.103449726719*x +1.92665749586
         };

\addplot[color=red,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.5mm,
         ]
         {
          0.0850917579094*x -1.02445254963
         };

\addplot[color=blue,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.5mm,
         ]
         {
          0.008334360454*x +0.406334090188
         };

\addplot[dashed,
          color=black,
          domain=-1:8, 
          line width=0.25mm,
         ]
         {
          -0.00909812720891*x +0.449836565041
         };
%\legend{ ,$RANSAC$,$MQ$,$ME$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\caption{Em preto, pontos localizados fora e, em azul, pontos localizados dentro da janela de interesse. Em vermelho, retas suportes das fileiras ajustadas por meio do RANSAC. Em tracejado, reta bissetriz associada ao par de retas suportes. Em azul, reta bissetriz filtrada (reta de refer\^{e}ncia).}
\label{resultado}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: your code snippet is not compilable. Please reduce it to small, but complete self contained document with `\documentclass{...}` on the beginning and `\end{document} on the end, which will show your problem. And not forget add data tables. From what you show so far can be concluded, that images haven't the same size: the first one has mark outside of graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually they are perfectly aligned, just not the way you want it. The problem is that in the first plot you have marks outside the axis, and this sets the bounding box of the figure wider than the others. So you need to reset the bounding box to follow, at least, the left axis. This can be done in two ways, as shown below. Since you use imported csv files that I do not have I made a new MWE. Since I have two examples I used `twocolumn` to get them side by side.

The first fix is adding `[trim axis left]` to the picture (or the axis). That means everything to the left of the axis is not regarded in the bounding box. I think this is a newer solution than the second below, but I also think I see a small misalignment in the plots. The upper is slightly left of the lower. It is barely visible and I am not sure it is actually there when you print it (I have not tried).

The second fix is more straight forward. After the plot reset the bounding box and set it yourself to the size of the axis.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\section*{First fix}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[%
    xmin=0,xmax=6,ymin=-2,ymax=6,
    width=7.5cm, height=5.5cm,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot[only marks,mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},mark size=2pt,color=black,fill opacity = 0.2]
    coordinates {(0,1) (1,0.5) (2,0.75) (3,0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    xmin=0,xmax=6,ymin=-2,ymax=6,
    width=7.5cm, height=5.5cm,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot[only marks,mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},mark size=2pt,color=black,fill opacity = 0.2]
    coordinates {(0.5,1) (1,0.5) (2,0.75) (3,0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
\section*{Second fix}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[%
    xmin=0,xmax=6,ymin=-2,ymax=6,
    width=7.5cm, height=5.5cm,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot[only marks,mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},mark size=2pt,color=black,fill opacity = 0.2]
    coordinates {(0,1) (1,0.5) (2,0.75) (3,0)};
  \end{axis}
  \pgfresetboundingbox
  \useasboundingbox (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    xmin=0,xmax=6,ymin=-2,ymax=6,
    width=7.5cm, height=5.5cm,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot[only marks,mark options={scale=1.5, fill=white},mark size=2pt,color=black,fill opacity = 0.2]
    coordinates {(0.5,1) (1,0.5) (2,0.75) (3,0)};
  \end{axis}
  \pgfresetboundingbox
  \useasboundingbox (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]